# How to match scala generic type?

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

Is there any way to match just on generic type passed in function?
I'd like to do:

```
def getValue[T](cursor: Cursor, columnName: String): T = {
    val index = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)
    T match {
        case String => cursor.getString(index)
        case Int => cursor.getInteger(index)
 }
```

I thought about something like `classOf` or `typeOf`, but none of them is acceptable for just types, but objects.

My idea was also to create some object of type `T` and then check its type, but I think there can be a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `ClassTag`.

```
val string = implicitly[ClassTag[String]]
def getValue[T : ClassTag] =
  implicitly[ClassTag[T]] match {
    case `string` => "String"
    case ClassTag.Int => "Int"
    case _ => "Other"
  }
```

Or `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

def getValue[T : TypeTag] =
  if (typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[String])
    "String"
  else if (typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[Int])
    "Int"
  else
    "Other"
```

Usage:

```
scala> getValue[String]
res0: String = String

scala> getValue[Int]
res1: String = Int

scala> getValue[Long]
res2: String = Other
```

If you are using `2.9.x` you should use `Manifest`:

```
import scala.reflect.Manifest
def getValue[T : Manifest] =
  if (manifest[T] == manifest[String])
    "String"
  else if (manifest[T] == manifest[Int])
    "Int"
  else
    "Other"
```

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek: It's possible to store type information in some addition field, but it'll break java compatibility. There is no way to avoid type erasure in types from java.

Comment: I know, I know. Just wishful thinking. Maybe I'm just a little bit spoiled by C#/F#.

Comment: @senia you can write `typeOf[String]` instead of `implicitly[TypeTag[String]].tpe` (import `typeOf` from `universe`)

Comment: @0__, @senia `error: object runtime is not a member of package reflect`

Comment: @squixy: `scalaVersion := "2.10.2"`. In 2.9.x you should use [`Manifest`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest).